# Reverse a string with php

Tags: php, string, reverse

I am trying to find a way to reverse a string, I've seen alternatives but i wanted to to it this way thinking outside the box and not using anyone else's code as an alternative, the code below reverses the string but I keep getting this error:

Notice: Undefined offset: 25 in C:\wamp\www\test\index.php on line 15

25 being the length of the string which is being deincremented.

```
//error_reporting(NULL);
$string = trim("This is a reversed string");

//find length of string including whitespace
$len =strlen($string);

//slipt sting into an array
$stringExp = str_split($string);

//deincriment string and echo out in reverse
for ($i = $len; $i >=0;$i--)
{
echo $stringExp[$i];
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Your string index starts at 0, so the 25th character's index is 24. Change your code so that $i goes from 24 to 0. As many posters have answered below, you should also look for a function to do what you need in the PHP function libraries.

Comment: Thanks I stumbled on the 0 being counted as One, and yes there are libraries to do this but I wanted to try and do it differently without them ;-)

Comment: I added an answer on your problem here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/30722030/137196. Feel free to adjust as needed. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others said, there's `strrev()` to do this.

If you want to build it on your own (for learning?): your problem is that you're starting with your index one too high - a string of length 25 is indexed from 0 to 24, so your loop has to look like this:

```
for ($i = $len - 1; $i >=0;$i--)
{
   echo $stringExp[$i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's where I was going wrong forgot that 0 it counted so when deincrimenting the length it was looking for 25 which wasn't there, and yes I know strrev is available but i was trying to do it without relying on pre-built functions. Youve saved me from a headache :-)

Answer (score 8):

You're trying much too hard, always consult the manual and/or a search engine to check if there are native functions to do what you want before you end up "reinventing the wheel":

> **strrev** — Reverse a string

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php

```
$string = "This is a reversed string";
echo strrev($string);
// Output: gnirts desrever a si sihT
```

Comment: Be careful when using `strrev` on a utf8 string! [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496493/strrev-dosent-support-utf-8/17496494#17496494)

Answer (score 4):

```
$string = 'mystring';
$length = strlen($string);

for ($i = $length; $i > 0; $i--){
echo $string[$i-1];
}

OUTPUT: gnirtsym
```

Answer (score 2):

You must get `$len-1` because string starts from `0` to `$len-1`

Answer (score 1):

There is a function for this [strrev](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo strrev("This is a reversed string!");
```

Answer (score 1):

php is quite complete in term of string function you just need to pass the string . thats why php is easy :)

use **strrev** php function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php

```
<?php
  echo strrev("This is a reversed string");
 ?>

// Output: gnirts desrever a si sihT
```

Comment: Thanks Yes strrev is the easy way but I was trying to work it out methodically ie(the long way) its for an interview I have today.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = $len-1; $i >=0;$i--)
{
  echo $stringExp[$i];
}
```

Since the index starts at 0

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop to

```
for ($i = $len-1; $i >=0;$i--)
{
echo $stringExp[$i];
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for as oezi above mentioned about the there being 24 array keys and not 25, cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use it:

```
echo $reversed_s = join(' ',array_reverse(explode(' ',"Hello World")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function stringReverse($string="Jai mata di")
{
    $length = strlen($string) - 1;
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $length + 1) {
        echo $string[$length - $i];
        $i++;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
class StringUtils {

    public function stringReverse($string){
        $arr1 = str_split($string);
        $arr2 = array();
        for($i = count($arr1); $i >= 0; $i--){
            $arr2[count($arr1) - $i] = $arr1[$i];
        }
        return implode("", $arr2);
    }
}
```