# Regex last word starting at end of string

Tags: regex

I have the following regex `\b(\w+)$` that works to find the last word in a string. However the longer the string, the more steps it takes.

How can I make it start the search from the end of the line?

Comment: What do you mean about more steps it takes?  Depending on language you could reverse the string.

Comment: then how do I make it more efficient?

Comment: How inefficient is it right now?  Do you have benchmarks or are you micro-optimizing?

Comment: Assuming you need this for a specific use-case: Why don't you make it work from the start of the string but reverse your entire string? That way a string like `This is my string` becomes `gnirts ym si sihT`. Then use regex to parse from the beginning of the string and the re-reverse your string parts: `gnirts` becomes `string`.

Comment: maybe I'm being too picky - I wanted the number of steps to remain the same regardless of the length of the string.

Comment: Split on `\W+` and take the last element.

Comment: @mtissington No, but if you reverse the string like I mentioned and used `^` instead of `$` it will only do 7 steps instead of X steps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answer

### Brief

Using the regex you specified `\b(\w+)$` you will get an increasing number of steps depending on the string's length (it will match each `\b`, then each `\b\w`, then each `\b\w\w` until it finds a proper match of `\b\w$`), but it still has to do that check on each item in the string until it's satisfied.

What you can do to get the last item of a string using regex explicitly is to flip the string and then use the `^` anchor. This will cause regex to immediately be satisfied upon the first match and stop processing.

You can search how to flip a string in multiple languages. Some examples for languages include the following:

- [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)
- [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string)
- [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100634/reverse-a-string-with-php)

### Code

[You can see the regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/kIOL0j/2)

Your programming language

```
// flip string code goes here
```

Regex

```
^(\w+)
```

Your programming language

```
// flip regex capture code goes here
```

### Input

```
This is my string
```

### Output

Converted to the following by flipping the string in your language

```
gnirts ym si sihT
```

Regex returns the following result

```
gnirts
```

Flip the string back in your language

```
string
```

### Explanation

Since the anchor `^` is used, it will check from the beginning of the string (as per usual regex behaviour). If this is satisfied it will return the match, otherwise, it will return no matches. Testing in regex101 (provided through the link in the **Code** section) shows that it takes exactly 6 steps to ensure that a match is made. It also takes exactly 3 steps to ensure *no* match is made. These values do not change with string length.

Comment: @Toto Thanks I caught that one too when revising, I removed it in the updated link and answer

Answer (score 1):

In most regex engines, you can't.

Regex engines work by consuming input from the start of the input.

---

You can programmatically do it with a simple decrementing loop over the characters starting from the last character. If you need more performance, using code over regex is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

It only works in `.NET`:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(Pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
Match match = rx.Match(Source);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be faster.

```
^.*\b(\w+)
```

• add `^.*` before and capture `\w+`
• drop the `$` if possible

Good luck!